# Roll back in SQL

Tags: sql

I used rollback concept in my procedure in `dom` table. After executing, then I ran the table like:

```
select * from dom
```

but the query executed continuously and did not stop. How can I stop this? Please help.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what are you doing exactly?

Comment: create proc dom1

as
begin
begin trans
insert into dom(value)

if  flag=0
rollback trans
else
commit

Comment: Please edit your question. And use the correct formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, you have this:

```
create proc
    dom1
as

begin

begin trans
    insert into dom(value)
if flag=0
    rollback trans
else
    commit
```

So what is `flag`? What is `value`? How are you passing in the value?

I don't think your code is useful for us to help you.

Take a look at Books Online for more information about ROLLBACK, or make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Er, ok then ... Glad I could help.